# 2.8 how to restore timeline cursor jump to left click

Tags: video-sequence-editor, graph-editor, dopesheet, timeline

in older versions of blender you could just click anywhere in the timeline and the cursor would jump to where you clicked, instead now it defaults to box select.

how do I change it back so i can just click anywhere in the time line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in left click mode then Shift + right click will get the playhead to move the position you click.

Answer (score -1):

Changing *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Select With* to *Right* restores the old behavior.